# How can I solve simple equations involving binary operators?

Tags: binary

I have some simple equations like:

```
A = (X AND 1779038349) XOR ((X AND 3144134329) XOR 7047511487)
```

Where A is some constant and X is unknown (all numbers are 32 bit unsigned integers).

How can I solve this for X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the $x\mapsto x{\,\rm xor\,}s$ is the inverse of itself for all $s$, and that ${\rm and}$ is *distributive* over ${\rm xor}$, and ${\rm xor}$ is *associative*,  we get

$\begin{align} A{\,\rm xor\,} 7047511487 &= X{\,\rm and\,}(1779038349{\,\rm xor\,}3144134329) \\ A' &=
X{\,\rm and\,}3513669172 = X{\,\rm and\,}0b11010001011011100101011000110100 \end{align}$

where $A'$ is another constant ($A'=A{\,\rm xor\,} 7047511487$). So, we get a solution only if the constant $A'$ has no digit $1$ in binary where the right side has $0$ digit, and in that case, on these places $X$ can be arbitrary. In other words, $X$ is masked by the bits of 3513669172 above, and where it contains $0$, $X$ can be arbitrary, when it contains $1$, that digit of $X$ has to be the same as the digit on the same place in $A'$ (from the right).